# Creating a Kanban Board in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure

We are using Azure Boards as a Project Management Tool where we capture customer requirements and then track all the work_items by creating a user_stories and splitting them into multiple tasks and so on.. We are using Agile Process and it works fine. However, we have some support based projects where we need a KANBAN Board. How do we create a KANBAN Board in Azure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest reading the official documentation(quickstart) from Microsoft, as there are Prerequisites and you may need to add a new team since you are using Agile => [Link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/boards/kanban-quickstart?view=azure-devops)